# Turn adjacency list into tuple array Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Let's say I have the following input:

`[(0, [1, 2]) , (2, [3, 4]) , (4, [])`

This is an adjacency list and I want to convert it as such:

`[(0,1), (0,2), (2,3), (2, 4)]` -- notice how there is no `4` mapping to anything

Here is what I have so far:

```
conv :: [(Int, [Int])] -> [(Int, Int)]

conv adj = map fn adj -- mapping (0, [1, 2]) should give me [(0, 1), (0, 2)]

fn:: (Int, [Int]) -> [(Int, Int)]

fn (rt, list) = -- somehow perform [(rt, l[0]), (rt, l[1]) ...]
```

Comment: `f m = concat $ map (\(x,y)-> zip (repeat x) y) m `

Comment: What does the `$` mean in this case?

Comment: $ lets me omit parentheses, it’s the same as `concat ( map (\(x,y)-> zip (repeat x) y) m )`

Comment: Alright, thanks, I will look more into zip and repeat to understand this

Comment: `$` is actually just function application: `f $ x` is defined as `f x`. Put that way, it initially looks useless, but `$` has very low precedence whereas function application has the highest precedence of all, so in practice it's helpful for avoiding brackets, exactly as @FrownyFrog says :)

Comment: @FrownyFrog: instead of using `zip (repeat x) y`, one can use `map (x,) y` with `TupleSections` :)

Answer (score 2):

*List comprehension* can do the trick:

```
conv :: [(a, [b])] -> [(a, b)]
conv xys = [(x, y) | (x, ys) <- xys, y <- ys ]
```

Or we can use `concatMap` here:

```
conv :: Foldable f => f (a, [b]) -> [(a, b)]
conv = concatMap (uncurry (map . (,)))
```

Here the inner function `uncurry (map . (,))` takes a tuple `(x, ys)` and thus performs a `map (x,)`: the `uncurry` basically unpacks the tuple `(x, ys)`, and calls `(map . (,)) x ys`, so that means that we obtain `(map (x,)) ys`. The above syntax uses the `TupleSections` extension, but we do not need to activate that extension in the real program, since we never write such syntax. Your `fn` function you defined is thus equivalent to `uncurry (map . (,))`.

We thus use this function in a `concatMap` that will pass the 2-tuples, and concatenate the lists these individual tuples create.

or we can use the "bind" [**`>>= :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-) function:

```
conv :: Monad m => m (a, m b) -> m (a, b)
conv = (=<<) (\(x, ys) -> ys >>= return . (x,))
```

or shorter:

```
conv :: Monad m => m (a, m b) -> m (a, b)
conv = (=<<) (uncurry (fmap . (,)))
```

the nice thing about the latter is that it also works with `Maybe`s, etc. For example:

```
Prelude> conv [(0, [1, 2]) , (2, [3, 4]) , (4, [])]
[(0,1),(0,2),(2,3),(2,4)]
Prelude> conv Nothing
Nothing
Prelude> conv (Just (3, Nothing))
Nothing
Prelude> conv (Just (3, Just 2))
Just (3,2)
```

Comment: Generalizing from a list comprehension to a monad comprehension (or just using plain old `do` notation) gives you `conv :: Monad m => m (a, m b) -> m (a, b)`. IMO, that's a more natural generalization than `Foldable` here.

Comment: Is this a way to do this using any of the fold operators?

Comment: @KSplitX: the second one uses a fold operator.

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage of `instance Traversable ((,) a)`, we have this remarkably short (and remarkably inscrutable) solution:

```hs
conv :: [(Int, [Int])] -> [(Int, Int)]
conv = (sequence =<<)
```

The most general type of `(sequence =<<)` is `(Monad m, Traversable t) => m (t (m a)) -> m (t a)`.